# Prevent users from creating event of particular record type from opportunity object

Tags: validation-rule, event

I want to pop up error whenever a permission set user tries to create an event of B type from an opportunity?
Event has two record types A,B
But the user who has permission set assigned Should not create an event of B type.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom permission set (like `Create_Event_B`) and assign those users who can create the Event.

In the validation rule, check as follows and throw validation error.

```
ISNEW() 
&& NOT($Permission.Create_Event_B) 
&& (RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Event_B')
```